# What do you call a URL path without a host name?

Tags: url, naming-conventions

Out of curiosity and the need to name a configuration setting properly: What do you call an URL that is an absolute path reference but without a domain?

- `http://www.domain.com/path/to/myfile` is an absolute, full URL.
- `../to/myfile` is a relative path.

What would you call `/path/to/myfile`?

Is there a convention? Am I just daftly overlooking the obvious? "absolute path" would work in a file system context, but in a URL context I fear confusion with the full URL.

Answer (score 13):

[RFC 3986 terms it as *absolute-path reference*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2):

> A
> relative reference that begins with a single slash character is
> termed an absolute-path reference.

But you can say just *absolute path* or *absolute URL/URI path*.

Comment: Useful fielding of this topic you can also find in [RFC 1808](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1808#section-2.2).

Answer (score 5):

It probably depends on the context, that's called `path-absolute` in the grammar of [RFC 3986 (Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986/#section-3.3). I think most people would call this an *absolute path*: that's also the terminology used by [RFC 1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808) (obsoleted by RFC 3986).

Answer (score 1):

Speaking in terms of URI as per RFC 2396, this just is a path, among scheme (http), authority, query and fragment (none in your case).

Comment: Oh, my bad. URI path is ALL the stuff after 'http://'. You can call it sub-domain path, though... :)

Comment: There is something more specific: RFC 1808, RFC 2396 and RFC 3986 all mention absolute paths (or absolute-path references).

Answer (score 0):

A Virtual Path? Physical Path would be more accurate I guess.

Comment: Virtual path and physical path in which context? There's no such terminology in RFC 3986.

Comment: +1, you're right. Turns out for years I've been using the wrong terminology!